# jq equivalent in power shell with indentation

Tags: json, powershell, pretty-print, object-graph

I am successfully using `jq.exe` installed on my windows with `choco install jq`:

```bash
$ echo '{"class": [{"name": "oren", "age": 6},{"name": "moish", "age": 200}]}' | jq.exe
{
  "class": [
    {
      "name": "oren",
      "age": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "moish",
      "age": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I achieve the same recursively indented format with power shell's native `ConvertFrom-Json` ?

```bash
$ echo '{"class": [{"name": "oren", "age": 6},{"name": "moish", "age": 200}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json

class
-----
{@{name=oren; age=6}, @{name=moish; age=200}} # <--- useless for real json files
```

I couldn't find anything in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: `'{"class": [{"name": "oren", "age": 6},{"name": "moish", "age": 200}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: Nothing wrong with reaching out to jq once in a while.